# Git rename file throughout history

Tags: git, refactoring

I have a situation that a prototype application was developed without paying much attention to the folder structure and naming.
As the prototype matured, at some point it was switched to follow the naming conventions, which included the name in the folder structure.

Before the project file was named `app_project.pro`, now it's named `app-project.pro`.
This refactoring change all happened in a single git commit.

The issue that occurs now is that the the IDE breaks every time there is a checkout prior the refactoring comment. This makes `git bisect` a hell to use.

Is there a way to do a refactor throughout history using a git command? I'm not aiming for an interactive rebase here but something that will just replace `app_project.pro` with `app-project.pro` in each occurence throuout whole history.

---

Idea: My current idea is to try and refactor everything in .git and than force push that to origin. I'm the only one using it so it shouldn't be a problem.

There are no notions of `app_project.pro` in the .git folder. I'm guessing the diffs aren't stored in ASCII>

Answer (score 2):

[**Tree filter**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) is what you want:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'if [ -f <file_name> ]
then
 mv <file_name> <new_file_name>
fi' --force HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could achieve what you want.

If you decide to change the name of your folder/files then git will consider as it is a different file and as you suggested this versioning not editable.

Even the built-in command `git mv oldname newname` is a shortcut for :

```
mv oldname newname
git add newname
git rm oldname
```